# Dynamic IDs on asp:TextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, webforms

This is my code, on a `.ascx` page :

```
<% for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) 
   { %>
    <asp:TextBox ID="myTextBox_<%=i %>" runat="server" Width="100%" CssClass="focus_out reset_content"></asp:TextBox>
<% } %>
```

but I get `myTextBox_<%=i %>` is not a valid identificator. So, how can I put "Dynamic IDs"?

Comment: One possibility to achieve the effect you're going for is to use an html attribute, and assign it based on the iteration in your loop. e.g. `data-id`

Comment: George : can you give an example?

Comment: instead of having a user control just for that why don't you use a `<asp:Repeater>` control with a `TextBox` control as template?

Comment: balexandre is correct, using an `<asp:Repeater>` or `<asp:ListView>` is the standard approach to this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a container for the textboxes, such as a Panel control, and then use the Page_Load in the code behind to loop through and add the text boxes to the panel.

Example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlContainer" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

            TextBox txtNewTextBox = new TextBox();
            txtNewTextBox.ID = "myTextBox_" + i;
            pnlContainer.Controls.Add(txtNewTextBox);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of this please?

Comment: i suspect he means looping in the `Page_Load` method and calling `someContainer.Controls.Add(new TextBox(){ID: "someId"});` for each text box, where `someContainer` is a `Panel` or other container

Comment: My real scenario, unfortunatly, it is a bit different! In fact, into the container, I need to have other html elements. So I won't add them looping the panel...

Answer (score 4):

Here is the link for [Dynamically adding textbox control in ASP.Net](http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/03/17/dynamically-adding-textbox-control-to-aspnet-table.aspx). Hope it works for you.